# Sort large chunk of text by adding together like terms, using Python?

Tags: python, sorting

Here is a sample chunk of data.

```
1med,2obs,3soc,1sed,3rhe,2hyp,1inti,1tea,1bod,4sto,1aur,1med,1sin,1ded,5obs
1act,4sed,3per,2inte,2soc,3dan,1intel,3lea,1intel,1inte,3aur,2soc,2neg,3log
2sed,5tea,3her,1medi,1pla,3rhe,3rid,3soc,2swi,3tea,1wri,3obs,3hyp,2aur,1tac
2per,2med,3pla,4intel,3dag,3act,2tac,4obs,1shi,1aur,1medi,1ste,1una,1bra,1hyp
3act,1dan,3ded,5intel,1inte,3inv,1medi,3obs,2soc,1spi,2ste,3rea,3wri,3mat
1intel,4obs
```

With some research of my own, I have figured out how to sort in the obvious and common ways. I can sort alphabetically for instance, or I can sort by number, or a variety of other different sorting methods.

However, I am wanting to combine like terms and sort. I can't find any reference to combining like terms. For instance, if the data consisted of:

```
1med,2obs,2obs,1med,5rhe
```

Then after the program processed the data, the output would display as such:

```
2med
4obs
5rhe
```

What am  I missing?

Comment: Is it always a 1-digit number followed by some string?

Comment: Yes. It is always a 1-digit number, followed by a string of 3-5 letters.

Comment: Use a dictionary that maps strings to frequencies.

Answer (score 4):

I used a much smaller version of your original list because you didn't quote the strings, so I couldn't just copy and paste it, but you get the idea.

```
>>> original_list
['1med', '2obs', '3soc', '2hyp', '1inti', '3med', '4soc']
>>> counter = {}
>>> for item in original_list:
...   try:
...     counter[item[1:]] += int(item[0])
...   except KeyError:
...     counter[item[1:]] = int(item[0])
... 
>>> counter
{'med': 4, 'obs': 2, 'hyp': 2, 'soc': 7, 'inti': 1}
>>> for k,v in counter.items():
...   print('%s%s' % (v, k))
... 
4med
2obs
2hyp
7soc
1inti
```

You split the string by slicing after the number (`item[1:]`) and then add the number to the count stored in the dict (`int(item[0])`), using it as the value instead if it isn't there already (`except KeyError`).

Answer (score 1):

Using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) you can detect the number and the letters. Then store their counts in a dict and combine it in the end.

```
my_str = "1med,2obs,2obs,1med,5rhe"

import re

data_as_lst = my_str.split(',')

words_dct = {}
for chunk in data_as_lst:    
    word = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', chunk)[0]
    num = int(re.findall(r'[0-9]+', chunk)[0])

    if word not in words_dct:
        words_dct.update({word: num})        
    else:
        words_dct[word] += num

results = []
for word in words_dct:
    results.append(str(words_dct[word]) + word)

print(results)
```

Probably not as fast as slicing suggested by others (I missed the comments saying that first character is always a single digit), but it's suitable for any number of digits.

Comment: This is indeed a good answer and the right way to do it if the string is not so well-behaved.

Answer (score 0):

```
thelist = ['1med', '2obs', '3soc', '1sed', '3rhe', '2hyp', '1inti', '1tea', '1bod', '4sto', '1aur', '1med', '1sin', '1ded', '5obs', '1act', '4sed', '3per', '2inte', '2soc', '3dan', '1intel', '3lea', '1intel', '1inte', '3aur', '2soc', '2neg', '3log', '2sed', '5tea', '3her', '1medi', '1pla', '3rhe', '3rid', '3soc', '2swi', '3tea', '1wri', '3obs', '3hyp', '2aur', '1tac', '2per', '2med', '3pla', '4intel', '3dag', '3act', '2tac', '4obs', '1shi', '1aur', '1medi', '1ste', '1una', '1bra', '1hyp', '3act', '1dan', '3ded', '5intel', '1inte', '3inv', '1medi', '3obs', '2soc', '1spi', '2ste', '3rea', '3wri', '3mat', '1intel', '4obs']
list_dict = {x[1:]: x[0] for x in thelist}
```

A short dictionary comprehension can fix this up for you in 1 line so long as the prefix number is >0 and <10.

Then if you want to print all of that back out you can do a list comprehension to do so, though the dictionary may be nicer.

```
recombined = [str(list(list_dict.values())[y])+list(list_dict.keys())[y] for y in range(len(list(list_dict.values())))]
for each in recombined:
    print(each)
```

To turn that into a list, instead of using Python I simply brute forced it with Notepad++. I did ctrl+h (find and replace), searched for the commas (,) and replaced with quote-comma-quote (',').

If you need to do this on a regular basis consider reading the information in as a CSV file and adding the data to a list before doing the dictionary comprehension.